# Twig - Get corresponding alphabet letter in loop

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to use the `loop.index` variable in twig to get the corresponding alphabet letter (1 = A, 2 = B, etc).

```
{% for item in form.items %}
     {% set nom_item = 'Item'~loop.index %}
{% endfor %}
```

How could I do to get alphabet letter in loop ? I can't find a twig function for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try with this!
{% set foo = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'] %}

{% for index,item in form.items %}
     {% set nom_item = 'Item'~foo[index] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 20):

Simplest solution

```
  {{ range('A','Z')[loop.index0] }}
```